# Onpage pagination is not working

Tags: jquery, html, triggers, pagination, click

I have a pagination page.At the first time, data and pagination links are generated from the server  and shown them in my view.I have a drop down list.For every next time I want change  the data and pagination links whenever dropdown list is changed without loading the page with jquery,ajax,json.I have successfully changed the data and links.I have created the pagination links as per first time server returns.But this time i can't  trigger the **ul>li>a** element.I don't know why !!!.But the same js2 code works for the pagination which the server returns.

Html:server returns

```
 <div class="pagination">
    <ul>
       <li class="disabled"><a >1</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://localhost:8070/poralekha/home/universities/5">2</a></li>
    </ul>  
 </div>
```

This works .

JS1:for pagination:

```
  var pagination=" ";
  pagination+="<ul >";

  for(var i=1; i<=data['varsities'].length ;i++)
    {
        pagination+="<li class='disabled'>";
        pagination+="<a href='#' class='page'  >";
        pagination+=i;
        pagination+="</a>";
        pagination+="</li>";

    }
   pagination+="</ul>";

  $('.pagination').html(pagination );
```

here class='page' has been used for just get the value of i when .page is clicked

Js2:common for both pagination

```
   $(".pagination > ul >li > a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("This index is clicked.");
    });
```

or

```
      $(".page").on('click', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          alert(" clicked.");
      });
```

In short i want trigger when .page is clicked. I am just about to be mad with this.How can i solve this plz?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead of `click()`:

```
    $(".pagination > ul >li > a").on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("This index is clicked.");
    });
```

For older version of jQuery use `live()` method:

```
    $(".pagination > ul >li > a").live('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("This index is clicked.");
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.i am using jquery-1.10.1.min.js.its not working :(

Comment: You shoud to update jquery to be abble bind events on objects that will be added to DOM after page load.